# Navigate between GWT modules

Tags: gwt

I've divided my GWT app into multiple modules, what's the best way to navigate between them?

Currently I'm using `Window.Location.assign("foo.html#bar")` but is there a better way?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`History.newItem` only works for history within the current module.  To change to another page I think the best way is to use `Window.Location.assign`.

I don't fully remember the issue (and perhaps it has been fixed now), but in our application we stopped using relative URLs as they would sometimes break (we have a comment referencing http://groups.google.com/group/Google-Web-Toolkit/browse_thread/thread/f79e7d5e002b48f6).

To this end we had a method that did the following:

```
public void goToRelativePage(final String relativeURL) {
  Window.Location.assign(GWT.getHostPageBaseURL() + relativeURL);
}
```

Comment: If I do this, I get the login.html page shown on the screen, but 

com.google.gwt.user.client.rpc.StatusCodeException: 0 
 at com.google.gwt.user.client.rpc.impl.RequestCallbackAdapter.onResponseReceived(RequestCallbackAdapter.java:209)
 at com.google.gwt.http.client.Request.fireOnResponseReceived(Request.java:287)