# How to open a new page (internal link) in GWT?

Tags: java, gwt, hyperlink

I have built a small webform for registration (username, password,email...). I want to open a new webpage(whose html is inside my project) that displays all the relevant data to the user after the successful registration (Thank you for your registration.... ,your username is ....bla bla). 
I found this (http://google-web-toolkit.googlecode.com/svn/javadoc/2.0/index.html?overview-summary.html) , but i don't know if i should use hyperlink or anchor or sth. else.

Tnx

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If the resource is relative then you probably want to use my solution from this question:

[Navigate between GWT modules](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3250976/navigate-between-gwt-modules/3255777)

This works for other GWT modules and non-GWT pages deployed relative to your page and this code could be invoked from any event you liked, e.g. on an image click.

The simplest approach is probably just an `<a href="foo.html">link</a>` element though...

Comment: Tnx, i used window.location.assign("mypage.hml") and placed this html file inside my war/projectname folder.

Answer (score 0):

You might have a look at my blog entry here: http://penwag.blogspot.com/2010/04/april-penwag-update.html.  I wrestled with navigation in the original design of my web site.  Later I changed paradigms, and the whole navigation became much simpler, and produced a lot of side benefits with respect to integration with third-party tools.  The blog entry discusses in detail the change and the benefits.