# Manipulations on a fetched page in GWT

Tags: java, gwt

I have a method that does any manipulations with the yahoo.com page (parsing it, changing texts on it, etc.) and finally my method saves all changes of Yahoo.com' page to the result.html.

I have button in Google Web Toolkit's page and a listener on it:

```
myButton.addClickHandler(new ClickHandler() {
public void onClick(ClickEvent event) {
changeYahoo(); }});
```

The question is how can I show in the same browser's window result page after button (myButton) is clicked?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One approach would be to set the inner HTML of the body element. Depends on the effect you would like to see.

Have not tested this code, but if you have the manipulated HTML as string, you may succeed by doing this:

```
Element e = RootPanel.getBodyElement();
e.setInnerHtml(changedYahooString);
```

Update: Did read your question again, you finally have a file on the server with the result? Then you should simply point your browser there and serve the page from the server. This answer should be useful for you then: 
[Navigate between GWT modules](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3250976/navigate-between-gwt-modules/3255777)